# 405 Response on post using axios in Vue 3.0 app to .Net Core 2.2 with AllowAnyMethod in policy

Tags: vue.js, axios, asp.net-core-2.2

I am losing my mind and having read a lot of blogs, SO questions and documents I am sure it is a simple fix that I am now completely blind to.

I have an axios post call from a vuejs app to a .net core 2.2 api project.  Following the Enable CORS guide from Microsoft I have used Access Policy in Services and decorated the controller. See the code below.

The pre-flight options response is 204 with a 405 response on the actual call citing allow: DELETE, GET, PUT as the permitted method ... what have I missed here?  I have .AllowAnyMethod in the policy but it seems to be completely ignored.  A colleague working with a WebAPI 2.2. project has the exact same code and it works.

**StartUp.cs**

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
  options.AddDefaultPolicy(
    builder =>
    {
      builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                    "http://www.contoso.com");
       });

   options.AddPolicy("VueFrontEnd",
       builder =>
       {
         builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:30001/")
                                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                                    .AllowAnyMethod();
          });
      });
```

**Controller**

```
[EnableCors("VueFrontEnd")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> DoesItExist(string searchString)
{            
  var data = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };
  var result = data.Any(searchString.Contains);

  return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
 }
```

**Vue**

```
getClientsByPartialString(search: string) {
        Axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'https://localhost:44380/api/values/DoesItExist',
            crossDomain: true,
            data: {
                name: 'world',
            },
        })
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to add axios interceptors and check if there an error before?

Comment: I have not.  I will be honest and confess to have not learned of them yet ... i will do so immediately.

Comment: Did you find some help with interceptor?

Comment: Didn't get to it last night, found a couple nice articles this morning so will give it a go soon.

Answer (score 1):

This makes me sad.  It was routing.

Adding [HttpPost("/TheApi")] decorator sorted it.

I am ashamed.  I was using the full URL http://localhost:port/api/values/themethod and routing was failing me despite it being set on the controller.

The one thing that concerns me is why this worked with GET and PUT and ONLY failed on POST.  I have no answer to that one.